# Duplicate data with FirebaseListAdapter and ListView on scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, adapter

I'm writing a simple workout log. Here I'm populating a view using the FirebaseListAdapter and its working ok when I initially load it. The problem is that when I have more data and scroll down, the data gets duplicated every time. I understand that the fragment is recreated every time I scroll down or up but I couldn't come up with a solution. The data in the image below is populated within the populateView function.

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView lv;
private FirebaseListAdapter adapter;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

public HistoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    lv = v.findViewById(R.id.lvHistory);
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Workouts").child(user_id);
    FirebaseListOptions<Workout> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Workout>()
            .setLayout(R.layout.workout)
            .setQuery(query, Workout.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull Object model, int position) {
            TextView workoutname = v.findViewById(R.id.workoutName);
            TextView exerciseInfo = v.findViewById(R.id.exerciseInfo);

            Workout workout = (Workout) model;
            workoutname.setText(workout.getWorkoutName().toString());

            int counter = 0;
            for (Exercise exercise : workout.getExercises()) {
                exerciseInfo.append(exercise.toString() + "\n");
            }
        }
    };

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
}
```

[Here is an image of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTjsx.jpg)

Comment: If you comment that for loop used inside the `populateView()`, does it solve your problem?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't solve it. The loop is there because I have to show all the exercises within a workout. Well its not about the loop I figured out but about populateView itself. I tried a little more but the thing is that populateView is being called multiple times. I am unfortunately new to the FirebaseListAdapter so I don't know what it is exactly.